How do I get Power BI to consistently display a 12 month interval on the x-axis?
Currently I have a dataset like so:
Name  |    Date    | Certificate Completed|
Apple   01/21/2024          Cert 1
Banana  04/20/2023          Cert 1
Cherry  11/01/2024          Cert 2
Desert  06/06/2023          Cert 4

I want to graph a line chart that has:

Months on the x-axis
The total Count of Certificates completed on the y-axis per month.

But I want the x-axis to start with July 2023 - June 2024 (Fiscal Year).
And I also want it to keep displaying it as a 12 month interval even if there were no data on those months. (I'd like it to count it as 0 if possible).
Thanks!

Are your counts all 1 for the same data or do you want Cert 4 to equal a count of 4?

Do you have a calendar table? You then set up a column to order your months to your cycle, and it will show the blanks months
